# Google cloud kubernetes cluster newbie question

Tags: gpu, google-kubernetes-engine, nodes, config, nvidia

I am a newbie of GKE. I created a GKE cluster with very simple setup. It only has on gpu node and all other stuff was default. After the cluster is up, I was able to list the nodes and ssh into the nodes. But I have two questions here.

1. I tried to install nvidia driver using the command:

```js
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/container-engine-accelerators/master/nvidia-driver-installer/cos/daemonset-preloaded.yaml
```

It output that:

```js
kubectl apply --filename https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/container-engine-accelerators/master/nvidia-driver-installer/cos/daemonset-preloaded.yaml
daemonset.apps/nvidia-driver-installer configured
```

But 'nvidia-smi' cannot be found at all. Should I do something else to make it work?

2. On the worker node, there wasn't the .kube directory and the file 'config'. I had to copy it from the master node to the worker node to make things work. And the config file on the master node automatically updates so I have to copy again and again. Did I miss some steps in the creation of the cluster or how to resolve this problem?

I appreciate someone can shed some light on this. It drove me crazy after working on it for several days.
Tons of thanks.

Alex.

Answer (score 0):

1. For the `DaemonSet` to work, you need to have a tag on your worker `Node` as `cloud.google.com/gke-accelerator` (see [this line](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/container-engine-accelerators/blob/master/nvidia-driver-installer/cos/daemonset-nvidia-mig.yaml#L41)). The `DaemonSet` checks for this tag on a node before scheduling any pods for installing the driver. I'm guessing a default node pool you create did not have this tag on it. You can find more details on this on the GKE docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/gpus).
2. The worker nodes, by design are just that *worker* nodes. They do not need privileged access to the `Kubernetes API` so they don't need any `kubeconfig` files. The communication between worker nodes and the API is strictly controlled through the `kubelet` binary running on the node. Therefore, you will never find `kubeconfig` files on a worker node. Also, you should never put them on the worker node either, since if a node gets compromised, the keys in that file can be used to damage the `API Server`. Instead, you should make it a habit to either use the master nodes for `kubectl` commands, or better yet, have the `kubeconfig` on your local machine, and keep it safe, and issue commands remotely to your cluster.

After all, all you need is access to an API endpoint for your Kubernetes API server, and it shouldn't matter where you access it from, as long as the endpoint is reachable. So, there is no need whatsoever to have `kubeconfig` on the worker nodes :)

Comment: Hi zer0, thanks tons first. You made it so clear. I will try what you said and get back here to let more people know in case it helps. Thanks again.

Comment: Awesome! Will look forward :)

Comment: Hi zero, hope you can still help on this. When I run the command "kubectl apply -f https://raw......" to install the nvidia driver, do I run it on the worker node? If yes, we have to ssh into the node to install it, right? 
BTW, I didn't find how to add the tag you mentioned. I was just trying a very simple cluster with just one gpu node. So, I did everything from command line.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: When you run that command to apply the daemonset, it will run "in your cluster". What it will do is, look for all the nodes in your cluster that match a certain annotation, and any node that matches it, it will put pods on it to install the driver. So you don't have to do anything to the node yourself, it is done automatically.

Comment: You can annotate the node simply by running `kubectl annotate <node-name> cloud.google.com/gke-accelerator:<gpu-type>`. The `<gpu-type>` list you can get from [this](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/gpus#multiple_gpus) page in the docs. Perhaps it will match the `gpu-type` you set on your node when creating the cluster.

Comment: Thanks, first, zer0. I annotated the node as you explained. I ran the daemon deployment command again. It sees it is still the same thing. Also, on Kubernetes's webpage, it says:

Running Pods on select Nodes
If you do not specify either, then the DaemonSet controller will create Pods on all nodes.
So, it should deploy to all nodes (in my case just one node) even the node selector is not specified.
When I ran the daemon deployment command, it's gave the info "daemonset.apps/nvidia-driver-installer created" and then went back to the prompt. The drive is still not installed on the node.

Comment: Hi zer0, the problem was resolved. I opened a ticket with Google about the issue. Surprisingly, after they told me they were able to install the driver, I was able to. I didn't change the way I created the cluster and installed the driver. 
I appreciate your comments. I really learned something from you :)